# How to embed youtube channel into site?

Tags: wordpress, video, youtube, video-streaming

What is the best way to embed an entire youtube channel into a site? Looks like the "custom player" generator was discontinued recently..

Im looking for more than just a video with a scroll bar. I want to replicate the experience of the actual channel as much as possible (see screenshot for example).

Anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this? [image]

Note: I have a wordpress site and have not seen any plugins either??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Google is steering the direction of [Cosmic Panda](http://www.youtube.com/cosmicpanda).  They're probably a ways off from having much in the way of developer tools.

Also check out [Kaltura's open source work](http://site.kaltura.com/Player-Templates.html).  This would give you a good head start over rolling your own, but it will still probably require a lot of programming if you're wanting something very specific.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. I didn't need to display all that information about the channel (like favorites, info etc..), but was in search of a channel player, which worked on iOS Safari, like iPad and iPhone.

I ended up writing my own: http://code.google.com/p/jq-youtube-player/ . It is based on jQuery, and requires only a .js and a .css file.

Feel free to use it, improve it, etc...

Answer (score 2):

I found this player at jsfiddle

And then updated it to fit a widescreen player at http://jsfiddle.net/Zbbbv/1068/

Answer (score 1):

Get the **playlist ID** from the "Play All" button in the new channel page, for example, see www.youtube.com/user/google right after the featured video.

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCtQ2UiRkZw&list=UUK8sQmJBp8GCxrOtXWBpyEA

Where **UUK8sQmJBp8GCxrOtXWBpyEA** is the playlist ID.

and use it to create the URL for the iframe:

> http://www.youtube.com/embed/?list=[playlistID]

Source: http://konstruktors.com/blog/web-design/3384-embed-youtube-channel-playlist/

Full list of Embed parameters: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent and short tutorial on how to do this here: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=4c414f514bc3f690&hl=en

Essentially, use this script:

```
<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/youtube.xml&amp;up_channel=[YOUR-CHANNEL-NAME]&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=390&amp;title=&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
```

Replace `[YOUR-CHANNEL-NAME]` with your channel name and it should work.

Comment: that just puts a small player on my page not the entire channel look.